# Plasma 5.27.8 Microsoft keyboard switch expression key to right ctrl

Tags: kde, keyboard, bluetooth, kubuntu

I have a *Microsoft Designer Compact Keyboard*. I recently installed Kubuntu and wanted to use the "expression key" key as a right ctrl. In windows it was a simple solution, changing the key to "application key" on the "Microsoft keyboard and mouse app" and then mapping that key to the right ctrl on Power Toys.

Is it possible to do this on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to do that

first way:

In system settings -> shortcuts -> custom shortcuts you can add keyboard shortcuts that execute commands. The command you need to execute is [xdotool](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/man1/xdotool.1.html)

second way:

install [input-remapper](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/input-remapper) then open it once opened, go to the editor and press the "expression key" in input then for output rebind it to right ctrl

Comment: Doesn't this interfere with other comands? For example, in vscode i use ctrl + shift + ` to open a new terminal, i use right ctrl because it's more comfortable, would the shortcut work in that case?

Comment: @AgustínBlando try it and see